# Python, How to take a comma separated sys argv, and make it like '1','2' (for MySQL "IN" Query)

Tags: python, mysql

I want to do the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT id,list_id,fname,lname,email,gender,birth_date,city,state,country,zip FROM lists_users WHERE status='a' AND list_id IN ('1','2')
```

where list_id will be a comma seperated sys arv.

In Python, 1,2,3,4 would all be ONE sys argv, correct?

I would need to then make it SQL compatible by adding single quotes around each comma separated value.  I'm guessing there is probably a one line very simple way to do this.  But very new to Python, so don't know where to start.  (Normally would do a for loop or something, and then manually ad single quotes around all values.

Comment: Try something and show it to us.

Comment: you can use this code `"'" + sys.argv[1].replace(',', "','") + "'"` . but this is not the right way, only the simplest way.

Comment: you could also just enter them as separate arguments and use str(tuple(sys.argv[1:]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` will contain strings, so you just need to wrap the values up for the query.

```
In [9]: sql_string = ",".join("'%s'"%i for i in sys.argv[1:])

In [12]: sql_string
Out[12]: "'1','3','4'"
```

In your SQL statement, this just gets substituted in as a string.

```
In [13]: "...AND list_id IN (%s)"%sql_string
Out[13]: "...AND list_id IN ('1','3','4')"
```

This works if your command line arguments are specified: `1 2 3`

If you want to specify them as `1,2,3`, then you would have to first run a `split` command:

```
In [9]: sql_string = ",".join("'%s'"%i for i in sys.argv[1].split(","))
```

Comment: I think this is it for sure, But for some reason I'm getting tho is '1,2', and it needs to be '1','2', which I don't get because I can go run python, say a=1,2,3, do the above join statement, and it works.  is sys argv treated differently?

Comment: this is exact code I have c&p,     sql_string = ",".join("'%s'"%i for i in sys.argv[2:])
    print(sql_string), print = '1,2,3'

Comment: You are probably specifying your command line arguments as `1,2,3`. Try giving it arguments like `1 2 3`

Comment: yea that def works.  wish I could do comma separated though.  answer below you + yours would work--if split() method worked.  (again super newb python), but I assume it'd be pretty easy to turn sysargv "2" into  something I can split? ...would it just be sysagrv[2] = str(a)?

Answer (score 0):

> I would need to then make it SQL compatible by adding single quotes around each comma separated value.

You have a bizarre and twisted definition of "SQL compatible". If the field is numeric, then they should be numbers. But make sure they *are* numbers first.

```
nums = sys.argv[whatever].split(',')
try:
  in_val = ','.join(str(int(x)) for x in nums)
except ValueError:
  print >>sys.stderr, "No! Bad!"
  sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: get error with this list object has no attribute 'split'